# How do I get count of records using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-3.0, flower

I have **"Library.xml"** file containing book records as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <book>
        <title>DBMS</title>
        <author>Korth</author>
        <publisher>Pragati</publisher>
        <price>500</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>C Programming</title>
        <author>Balguruswami</author>
        <publisher>Vision</publisher>
        <price>1250</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>DBMS</title>
        <author>Balguruswami</author>
        <publisher>Vision</publisher>
        <price>1300</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>DBMS</title>
        <author>Ramakrishna</author>
        <publisher>Nirali</publisher>
        <price>350</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>C++</title>
        <author>E Balguruswami</author>
        <publisher>Techmax</publisher>
        <price>350</price>
    </book>

</library>
```

How do I get count of books of DBMS only using **XQuery - FLOWER** ?
I've tried this:

```
let $books := (doc("LibraryXML.xml")/library/book)

    return <result>
    {
        for $x in $books
        where $x/title = "DBMS"
        return count($x)
    }
    </result>
```

And according the **library.xml** the answer should be 3. But I'm getting it as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>1 1 1</result>
```

Comment: You're probably coming from a SQL background, where every query is a SELECT, and therefore assuming that in XQuery every query is a FLWOR. But FLWOR is needed only for the most complex queries. Most simple queries can be done with a simple XPath expression such as`count(//title)`.

Answer (score 2):

To do it in XQuery 3.0 there is no need in a full FLWOR expression with all clauses.

Check it out.

> XQuery

```
let $library := doc("e:\Temp\LibraryXML.xml")/library/book[title='DBMS']
return <result>{count($library)}</result>
```

> Output

```
<result>3</result>
```

Comment: And even more simple, do it in one-line statement without letting a variable: `<result>{count(doc("e:\Temp\LibraryXML.xml")/library/book[title='DBMS'])}</result>`

Comment: Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer